# .htaccess to load index.php file for friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this url:

```
www.mywebsite.com/news/best-ever-phones
```

The part `best-ever-phones` is variable and could be anything.
`index.php` file is checking database for article with url `best-ever-phones`

The problem is that in `./news/.htaccess` file I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?article=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which is supposed to load `index.php` file but server returns error `404 Not found` when I visit `www.mywebsite.com/news/best-ever-phones` url.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.+)$   index.php?article=$1   [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with Rewrite base and your relative path. But this is how i'ld do it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   Options -Indexes

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z-.]+)/?$ news.php?article=$1  [NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
  </IfModule>
```

This should fix you up, rename your index to news.php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give this a shot:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-\/]+)\/?$ index.php?article=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is presuming that you want the / character to appear in your `$article` variable, so you can logically separate different parts of the friendly URI if you want to in `/news/index.php`.  Otherwise, single segment friendly URIs like `/news-item-1` or whatnot can end with a trailing slash or not.

Really you don't want trailing slashes, as it might result in duplicate content penalties for loading the same page with a different URL (the / counts), so you could either not match `\/?` outside of the capture group or 301 redirect in index.php to the URL with the trailing slash removed.  This way you also have clean query arguments, e.g. `/news/something-big?orly=yes` instead of `/news/something-big/?orly=yes`

I am using [this site](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) to test the rewrites.  Otherwise untested as we don't have your code handy, so no way to tell whether it would work or not in your environment.

Answer (score -1):

This code is used when we click on any url it will hide its extension.
But If you want to goto index.php page then write

```
echo '<a href="index.php">Index Page </a>';

  ?>
```